# Get public key for new cert from k3s

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, k3s

So I got locked out of my Kubernetes instance, presumably due to a cert expiration. It was created with k3sup, by someone with a lot more Kubernetes experience than me.

To dig into the issue, I used AWS session manager to connect to the instance. When I ran `sudo kubectl get pods -A` from within the instance, I got the same error as I got from my local machine:

```
error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)
```

I then ran `sudo systemctl restart k3s` to restart the kubernetes, and which supposedly rotates the certs. Now `kubectl` commands work from within the container, which is great, but still not from my local machine.

If this did rotate the cert as I assume, I think I need the new public key for my local `~/.kube/config`. Where do I get this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the updated certs in the kube config at `/etc/rancher/k3s/k3s.yaml`